# Deformable convolution in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to use the `tensorlayer` in python 3.5 to run a simple code. I have this error::

```
[TL] DeformableConv2d ab: n_filter: 32, filter_size: (3, 3) act:relu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorlayer/deprecation.py", line 24, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorlayer/layers/convolution.py", line 971, in __init__
    tf.reshape()
TypeError: reshape() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tensor' and 'shape'
```

The code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorlayer as tl

inp = tf.zeros([1,50,50,3])
inp = tl.layers.InputLayer(inp, 'inp')

offset = tl.layers.Conv2d(inp, 18, (3,3), (1,1), padding="SAME")

d = tl.layers.DeformableConv2d(inp, offset, 32, (3,3), name='a')
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bug fix has been implemented, however we have not released it yet.
If you wish to install TL from sources, you can do the following:

```
pip uninstall tensorlayer  
pip install --upgrade tensorflow     # if you do not use GPU support
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu # if you use GPU support
pip install git+https://github.com/tensorlayer/tensorlayer.git
```

The RC release for 1.8.6 should come by the end of the month.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,, I did that but a new error appear -->             ( ** ImportError: __init__.py : Could not import TensorLayer.
Error: cannot import name 'getfullargspec'  **)             
I tried to install the statsmodels but it does not work too

Comment: I have tested with a clean environment, it perferctly works. Please make sure that you use the latest version of TF. I have edited my post with TF related commands.

Comment: Btw. your issue gave me the idea to create this PR: https://github.com/tensorlayer/tensorlayer/pull/644

Comment: Thank you so much, Jonathan. actually I installed Tensorflow 1.8.0 as you mention and the Tensorlayer worked successfully  ^_^